# Calculate a centre point of multiple lat, long points in a data-frame

Tags: r, geospatial, geosphere

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
site   lat      long 
bras2  41.21   -115.11
tex4   45.3    -112.31
bras2  41.15   -115.15 
bras2  41.12   -115.19
```

For samples with the same `site` name, I want to calculate their centre point and then add it as a column to the dataset. Some `site` names are duplicated twice, other three times, other four times.

Like this:

```
site   lat      long    centre_lat  centre_long 
bras2  41.21   -115.11  value here     value here
tex4   45.3    -112.31  45.3           -112.31 
bras2  41.15   -115.15  value here     value here
bras2  41.12   -115.19  value here     value here
```

How can I do this?

Comment: A midpoint is the single point that sits on the geodesic that connects two points and is equidistant from those two points.  Whatever you think the midpoint between _three_ points is, this is not the calculation that `midPoint` calculates. It expects two points only. Are you thinking of the _centroid_ of multiple points?

Comment: Yes, a centroid. Thank you so much, I was mistaken with regards to what a midpoint is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using spatial data, you should look into using the `sf` package.  It handles geometries and functions for operating on them well.

Code below shows using both `sf::st_centroid` and `geosphere::centroid`.  I prefer `sf`'s way of doing things.

```r
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text= "site   lat      long 
bras2  41.21   -115.11
tex4   45.3    -112.31
bras2  41.15   -115.15 
bras2  41.12   -115.19")


library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
library(sf)

# Using sf's st_centroid
df_sf <- st_as_sf(df, coords = c('long', 'lat'))

centroids_sf <- df_sf %>%
  group_by(site) %>% 
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>% 
  st_centroid

  
# Using geosphere::centroid
centroids_geoshpere <- df_sf %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  filter(n() >2)  %>% ## geosphere needs polygons therefore 3+ points
  st_union() %>%
  st_cast('POLYGON') %>%
  as('Spatial') %>% # geoshpere expects SpatialPolygons objects
  centroid() 
  

centroids_geoshpere
#>         [,1]     [,2]
#> [1,] -115.15 41.16001
centroids_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -115.15 ymin: 41.16 xmax: -112.31 ymax: 45.3
#> CRS:            NA
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   site         geometry
#> * <chr>         <POINT>
#> 1 bras2 (-115.15 41.16)
#> 2 tex4   (-112.31 45.3)
```

Looks like thery're close enough to the same point. I don't think `geosphere::centroid` can give a centroid for a single point, but may be wrong.  `sf::st_centroid` has no problem with 1,2, or more points.
<sup>Created on 2020-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much. Could I ask how will this code deal with cases where there are 2 points and a polygon cannot be made? Will it just ignore these cases?

Comment: The `geosphere` method above will remove locations with fewer than 3 points.  The `sf` method will work for 1, 2 and 3+ points.  I would suggest the `sf` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the means grouped by site names using `ave` after stripping off the site numbers using `gsub`.

```
within(dat, {
  g <- gsub("\\d", "", site)
  mid.lat <- ave(lat, g)
  mid.long <- ave(long, g)
  rm(g)
})
#    site   lat    long mid.long mid.lat
# 1 bras2 41.21 -115.11 -115.150  41.160
# 2  tex4 45.30 -112.31 -112.310  45.300
# 3 bras2 41.15 -115.15 -115.150  41.160
# 4 bras2 41.12 -115.19 -115.150  41.160
# 5  foo1 42.10 -123.10 -123.225  42.225
# 6  foo2 42.20 -123.20 -123.225  42.225
# 7 foo11 42.30 -123.30 -123.225  42.225
# 8 foo12 42.30 -123.30 -123.225  42.225
```

Or, if you depend on the `NA`:

```
within(dat, {
  g <- gsub("\\d", "", site)
  n <- ave(site, g, FUN=length)
  mid.lat <- NA
  mid.long <- NA
  mid.lat[n > 1] <- ave(lat[n > 1], g[n > 1])
  mid.long[n > 1] <- ave(long[n > 1], g[n > 1])
  rm(g, n)
  })
#    site   lat    long mid.long mid.lat
# 1 bras2 41.21 -115.11 -115.150  41.160
# 2  tex4 45.30 -112.31       NA      NA
# 3 bras2 41.15 -115.15 -115.150  41.160
# 4 bras2 41.12 -115.19 -115.150  41.160
# 5  foo1 42.10 -123.10 -123.225  42.225
# 6  foo2 42.20 -123.20 -123.225  42.225
# 7 foo11 42.30 -123.30 -123.225  42.225
# 8 foo12 42.30 -123.30 -123.225  42.225
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(site = c("bras2", "tex4", "bras2", "bras2", "foo1", 
"foo2", "foo11", "foo12"), lat = c(41.21, 45.3, 41.15, 41.12, 
42.1, 42.2, 42.3, 42.3), long = c(-115.11, -112.31, -115.15, 
-115.19, -123.1, -123.2, -123.3, -123.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you. One question - is `ave` a mean in this case? So, is it simply taking a mean of all latitudes and longitudes under the same `site` name? I am not sure if one can calculate centres like this due to the curvature of the Earth? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @fifigoblin Yes, `ave` groups first argument by second argument and applies a function that defaults to `mean`, see `help("ave")`. I admit not to be a specialist, but when considering GPS coordinates as rectangular projections the curvature shouldn't matter. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52652658/6574038) they calculate the centroids similarly with mean values.

Comment: @fifigoblin The calculation the would be based on [this centroid formula](https://www.mathwords.com/c/centroid_formula.htm) .

Answer (score 2):

The geosphere package has a function `centroid` to solve problems such as this one.
It as long as there more than one point in shape it is straight forward.  Most of the code below involves handling the single point case in the example above.

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text= "site   lat      long 
bras2  41.21   -115.11
tex4   45.3    -112.31
bras2  41.15   -115.15 
bras2  41.12   -115.19")


library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)

df %>% group_by(side) %>% centroid(.[ ,c(3,2)])

sites <- split(df, df$site)
results <-lapply(sites, function(x) {
   if(nrow(x)>1 ) {
     value <- as.data.frame(centroid(x[, c(3,2)]))
   }
   else {
      value <- x[1, c(3,2)]
      names(value) <- c("lon", "lat")
   }
   value$site <- x$site[1]
   value
})

answer<-bind_rows(results)

      lon      lat  site
1 -115.15 41.16001 bras2
2 -112.31 45.30000  tex4
```